# Separate controls with winform data binding

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

currently I have two combo boxes where I am using data binding to bind the combo box to an object I have. Problem is that the combo boxes are bound together, so if I change combo box A, combo box B will change with combo box A.

```
cboHomeTeam.ValueMember = cboHomeTeam.ValueMember;
cboHomeTeam.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboHomeTeam.DataSource = teams;

cboAwayTeam.ValueMember = cboAwayTeam.ValueMember;
cboAwayTeam.DisplayMember = "Name";
cboAwayTeam.DataSource = teams;
```

How can I go about making each combo box unique but still being bound to an object?

Comment: can't you give `.ValueMember` as property name like 'ID' or something?

Comment: Well I gave .ValueMember the control hoping that would work, the objects are bound to the combo box, it's just that all combo boxes are bound to one another, so if I change 1 combo box, they all change

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to handle this situation is to do exactly what your need is: "Update one combobox when the other changes"

```
cboHomeTeam.SelectedIndexChanged += ( s, e ) => cboAwayTeam.SelectedIndex = cboHomeTeam.SelectedIndex;
cboAwayTeam.SelectedIndexChanged += ( s, e ) => cboHomeTeam.SelectedIndex = cboAwayTeam.SelectedIndex;
```